# Блок-схема алгоритма

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Как на блок-схеме подать свою функцию ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
 
<sub>([источник](http://radikal.ru/F/s017.radikal.ru/i431/1111/db/9757caa47a65.jpg.html))</sub>

Вот, как тут.

Answer (score 8):

[ГОСТ](http://cert.obninsk.ru/gost/282/282.html) [говорит](http://www.fvn2009.narod.ru/Manuscripts/Algorithmization/algorithm8.htm): 
 1. Вызываем так: [image]
 2. Объявляем содержимое - в овале `ИмяФункции(Арг1,Арг2.....)`, а дальше как обычно, последовательность действий, в конце овал - возвращаемое значение

Answer (score 1):

Ну, наверное, нарисовать прямоугольный блок и в нём написать название функции и принимаемые ей параметры (я обычно так делал), к блоку можно добавить комментарий. Или написать название функции в комментарии к блоку, а в самом блоке написать действие, которое выполняет эта функция.